# Can ngrx/router-store 4 be used with ngrx-store 2.2?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use this combo together:

```
"@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.3",
"@ngrx/router-store": "^4.0.4",
"@ngrx/store": "^2.2.2",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^3.2.4",
"ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.1.9",
"typescript": "~2.3.4",
"rxjs": "^5.4.0",
```

I have seen issues with `ngrx-store-freeze` and was getting `Cannot add property _resolvedData, object is not extensible` errors but I don't know if this is due to version mismatch ([The migration guide](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#ngrxstore) says TS 2.4.x is required) or misconfiguration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment you have to use a custom route serializer, like so (from ngrx 4 example app):

```
export class CustomRouterStateSerializer
  implements RouterStateSerializer<RouterStateUrl> {
  serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateUrl {
    const { url } = routerState;
    const queryParams = routerState.root.queryParams;

    return { url, queryParams };
  }
}
```

and provide it in your app module:

```
providers: [
    { provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomRouterStateSerializer },
]
```